# The visual studio code and the android studio do not recognize the IOS simulator

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, ios-simulator, macos-catalina

I have a MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7, I downloaded Xcode outside the App Store with version 12.4 and I can't update it to version 13 because I should have version 12 or newer. What can I do to get Visual Studio Code and Android Studio to recognize the IOS simulator.

I already try with these commands:
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch

I have been searching the solution but nothing help.